# Android Emulator instance does not show "Allow USB Debugging" confirmation to authenticate

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my mobile app in the Android Emulator from Android Studio. When I run the app, it prompts me to select the emulator instance:

[image]

When I select an emulator instance the build of the application starts and the emulator selected boots up.

[image]

After the build completes, Android Studio tells me that its "waiting for the target device to come online" so that it can authenticate with the bridge.

After waiting for some time, I do not get an "Allow USB Debugging" confirmation with an RSA thumbprint so I enable developer mode and go into the settings.

I then try and turn the setting "USB Debugging" off and then back on, I then restart the ADB service on my computer which results in the ADB service asking me to authorise the device (which I cant get the confirmation for)

[image]

I have tried this with a few other Android versions, which of only one has worked (API 27) (This version showed me the allow confirmation window as soon as the OS booted) I also checked to see if developer options were enabled on the working OS (API 27), they were not which indicates that the OS images are pre-configured as they are emulators and I shouldn't need to touch any of the settings.

This feels like its an image problem as one of the images (API 27) does work. Does anyone know why I cannot get the other API versions to give me a prompt to authenticate with the remote target?

One thing to note:
On the versions that do not work, I cannot see a USB port on the device under `Developer Options -> Select USB configuration` but on the one working image I can see the USB port is detected and is set to "Charging".

API 27 (The image that works):

[image: API 27 (The image that works)]

API 25 (An image that does not work):

[image]

[image]

This is the prompt I expect to see so that the ADB service can communicate with the device:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing same problem, but solved by wiping data and killing and restarting the adb server, but it also not worked for again*
So , I used

```
Emulaor with no Play support
```

[image: select no play store emulator]

it only solved mine.
Hope it will be helpful to anybody else

Comment: I need emulator with Google Play, and the procedure from this answer has to be repeated each time.

Comment: This works for me too in emulator with no play support.

Comment: still waiting for another people to come up with solutions in emulator with Play Services in 2022

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's stupid, but it works, it's not stupid, right?

1. Go to Control Panel -> Power Options -> Edit Plan Settings -> Change advansed power settings
2. Change Minimum processor state and Maximum processor state to 5% and Apply

[Control Pannel Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr7iT.png)

3. Start Emulator (Cold boot)
4. Spam Allow button, when "Allow USB Debuging" window pops up.
5. Change power settings back

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to fix the issue,

**Method 1: Reset Android ADB Authentication Key**

**For Linux/macOS:**

- Open a file explorer and navigate to the `.android` folder located at
  ~/.android/.
- Delete both `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` files from the `.android` folder.
- Restart ADB, and it will automatically generate a new authentication
  key pair.

**For Windows:**

- Open File Explorer and go to the following path (Replace username
  with your actual Windows username):

  ```
  C:\Users\username\.android
  ```
- Inside the `.android` folder, find and delete the `adbkey` and
  `adbkey.pub` files.
- After deleting the files, restart ADB. It will create a fresh set of
  authentication keys.

**Method 2: Adjust Power Settings and Perform Cold Boot**

- Change your computer's power settings to reduce the processor state
  to 5%.
- Start the Android emulator with a cold boot. This ensures a
  clean and fresh start for the emulator.